# Disable all weekends and specific days plus enable mothers day

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, woocommerce

I have the following code already working well in functions.php - I want to enable mothers day though (12 may 2019) which falls on a Sunday. How to do I add this to the return string?

```
    function custom_adjust_datepicker_range () {
        if ( is_checkout() ) {

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var disabledDays = [
     "1-1-2019","1-1-2020","2-1-2019","28-1-2019","27-1-2020","4-3-2019","2-3-2020","19-4-2019","10-4-2020","22-4-2019","13-4-2020","25-4-2019","25-4-2020","27-4-2020","3-6-2019","1-6-2019","30-9-2019","28-9-2020","25-12-2018","25-12-2019","25-12-2020","26-12-2018","26-12-2019","26-12-2020","27-12-2018"
    ];
    jQuery( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 2,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
    var isDisabled = (jQuery.inArray(string, disabledDays) != -1);
    return [(day != 1 && day != 0 && !isDisabled), ''];
}
});
    </script>
    <?php
        }
    } // End custom_adjust_datepicker_range()
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_adjust_datepicker_range', 50 );
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var disabledDays = [
    "1-1-2019", "1-1-2020", "2-1-2019", "28-1-2019", "27-1-2020", "4-3-2019", "2-3-2020", "19-4-2019", "10-4-2020", "22-4-2019", "13-4-2020", "25-4-2019", "25-4-2020", "27-4-2020", "3-6-2019", "1-6-2019", "30-9-2019", "28-9-2020", "25-12-2018", "25-12-2019", "25-12-2020", "26-12-2018", "26-12-2019", "26-12-2020", "27-12-2018"
  ];

  var dtf = 'd-m-yy';

  function getMothersDay(y) {
    var mayFirst = new Date(y, 4, 1);
    var dayOfWeek = mayFirst.getUTCDay();
    var firstSunday;
    if (dayOfWeek == 0) {
      firstSunday = mayFirst;
    } else {
      firstSunday = new Date(y, 4, 1 + (7 - dayOfWeek));
    }
    var mothersDay = new Date(y, 4, firstSunday.getDate() + 7);
    return mothersDay;
  }

  function isMothersDay(dt) {
    return (jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(dtf, dt) == jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(dtf, getMothersDay(dt.getFullYear())));
  }

  jQuery("#delivery_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 2,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(dtf, date);
      var isDisabled = jQuery.inArray(string, disabledDays);
      var result = [
        true,
        "",
        ""
      ];
      switch (true) {
        case isMothersDay(date):
          // Mother's Day
          result = [
            true,
            "mothers-day",
            "Mother's Day"
          ];
          break;
        case (isDisabled >= 0):
          // Disable Days
          result[0] = false;
          break;
        case (day == 0):
        case (day == 6):
          // Weekends
          result[0] = false;
          break;
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Delivery Date: <input type="text" id="delivery_date"></p>
```

See More: [How to calculate Mother’s Day in JavaScript](https://joshtronic.com/2017/05/14/how-to-calculate-mothers-day-in-javascript/)

This example was based on first Google search result I performed. In the future, you may want to search for basic examples.

This is not adjusted for WordPress, so you will need to adapt the code to your needs.

You have 3 basic checks:

- Is the date Mother's Day
- Is the date in the array of dates
- Is the date a weekend day

You might have other scenarios arise so using a `switch()` might be easier overall. I move from the least common condition to the most common condition. You could add more and only check if it's Mother's Day if the month is May and they day of the month is within the first 2 weeks: `(date.getMonth() == 4 && date.getDate() < 15)`.

Hope this helps.